# Pip,Easy_Install not working due to an error thrown by the subprocess module?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, subprocess, easy-install

## Suddenly pip and easy_install have stopped working.

#### I guess this is due to some exception thrown by the subprocess module.How should i fix pip?

> **Even easy_install throws the same exception.**
> **My pip,easy_install and IDLE have been broken.**

These errors are shown
*Pip*:
[image: Error thrown by Pip]

*Easy_install*:
[image: Error thrown by easy install]

> **Note:I have tried using get-pip.py to reinstall pip,it throws the same exception**
>
> Pip exception text:[Pip exception paste_bin](https://pastebin.com/EqQxmF1Y)
> Easy install exception text: [Easy_install paste_bin](https://pastebin.com/ZXm8uHVg)
> The commands executed were:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

> And

```
easy_install
```

Comment: Please paste the text directly in code marks instead of posting pictures.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post and make it text instead of images? Copy/paste from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've fixed it. I copied my conda subprocess file and replaced my subprocess file with it.(I have 2 seperate installations)

**Step by step details:**

> 1.Backup you current subprocess file(to rollback if it does not work)
>   2.Open your conda **Lib** folder
>   3.Find the subprocess file (**subprocess.py**)
>   4.Replace it with your conda subprocess file